# display sub-menu of parent menu from parent id php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
   $page= $objPage-> get_page(); 
   $id = isset($_GET['id']);
   $child= $objPage-> get_child_page($id);  
?>

     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
            <?php 
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($page) ) { ?> 
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-  expanded="false">       
         <?php echo $row['title']; ?> <span class="caret"></span> 

         </a>       
           <?php } ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Function `get_page`:**

```
function get_page($id="") {
 $sql = "SELECT "; if( !empty($field) ){ 
$sql .=" title FROM page WHERE page_id>1 " ; 
} else {
 $sql .= " * FROM page "; 
} 
if( !empty($id) ){ 
$sql .=" WHERE page_id=".$id; 
} else { 
$sql .=" WHERE parent_id= -1"; 
} 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() ); 
if( !empty($id) && $result ){ 
$value = mysql_fetch_array($result) ; 
return $value; 
} 
return $result; 
}
```

**Function `get_child_page`:**

```
function get_child_page($id){ 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM page WHERE parent_id= $id"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
 return $result; 
}
```

i got the parent menu which has the parent id -1 but i want to display the child menu from parent id .. any solution ??

Comment: change `get_child_page` to `get_page_children`.

Comment: get_child_page($id) is my function ...

Comment: ops, i thought you are working on `WP`!

Comment: can you also add your function here?

Comment: I've added your functions to your question

Comment: where from you get `$page`? `mysql_fetch_array($page)` will be `mysql_fetch_array($child)`??

Comment: $page= $objPage-> get_page(); i have assigned in my php code, that is for parent menu.. :-)